# Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Setup Fails [0x80070652]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, redistributable

Installed Microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable exe before completion of the complete download in windows 7 pc. hence installation did not happen properly due to corrupt source. now i tried to uninstall and install again with the new exe the following error comes:

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Setup Fails [0x80070652] - another installation is already in progress. complete that installation before proceeding to install.**